# How do you parse a log file by identifying issues

Tags: java

I have a log file,I need to parse that file by identifying salient issues and writing them to a new file. Please guide me, any help will be appreciated.

Sample of the log file:

> Processing audio links...
>   Generating final TOC...
>   Generating concept and keyword anchors in output files...
>   Generating Index...
>   Generating Concepts...
>   Resolving links in output files...
>   Failed to update: The 'br' start tag on line 8 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'p'. Line 10, position 5.
>   Missing cross-referenced file: C:\tfs\Ver12.00\ua_dev\ua-test-bamboo\doc\Importee\en-US\Output\ffd\HTML5_X\Content\Cross_reference_X_BEFORE.htm
>   Generating Search Database...
>   Generating final output...
>   Generated Importee.htm
>   Saving result set...
>   Output generated in 4 second(s).

If I have to pickup keywords like `Missing` or `Error`, how do I do that?

Comment: first step would be to determine how you are going to recognize each individual log message. from the sample you can use "..." to identify when a log message ends.

Comment: once you can correctly parse each log message all there is left to do is for each log message, search for a given string like "Missing" and add it to a container, where each container of log messages get written to the correct salient issue file.

Comment: You can also use grep with pipes in a terminal. It's nice :) Start with that: `grep "Missing" myLog.log > salient.log`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how big the log will be, but if the example is about the size of the output in your example, you can do the following:

```
return logString.indexOf("Missing") != -1;
```